# Matlab after enter Ctrl+c, Can we execute some code or calling a function?

Tags: matlab

Sometimes, Matlab code may run a long time. 
I want to stop it - enter Ctrl+c, But I also want to execute some code after that.
e.g.

```
for i = 1:100000,
   M(i) = function(i,values);
end
```

Even if this for loop is not over, stop by Ctr+C or abnormal situation etc. I also want to call another function to do other process.

```
N = new_func(M)
save(N)
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, you could interrupt the executor using Ctrl+C and then run your function, or in Matlab 2016, you can pause the executor and then run your function.

Comment: So you want to add something like a callback that executes automagically everytime an "abnormal situation" occurs or the user presses ctrl+c ?

Comment: @Matt, Yes, I want a callback for an "abnormal situation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in to the `onCleanup` object. You create an `onCleanup` object by giving it some code that you'd like to run when your code finishes - and it does this whether the code finishes naturally, with an error, or with Ctrl-C.

There's a small restriction on its use - it needs to be used within a function, not a script (because it actually executes its code when the `onCleanup` object goes out of scope and is deleted, rather than specifically when your code ends). But usually that's not much of a restriction.

Comment: I run function like this 
```
function [] = action()
sum = 0;
for i=1:10000,
    sum = sum + i;
end
error('evoke an error')
disp(sum)
finishup = onCleanup(@() myCleanupFun());
end
```
my cleanup function
```
function myCleanupFun()
disp('myCleanupFun')
end
```
Should ```disp('myCleanupFun')``` be executed ? But my code just stop after ```error('evoke an error')```. Thx.